# Porting from Windows to Mac

Tags: c#, .net, windows, macos, porting

I have a program on .NET 4 for Windows. I'm trying to port it for Mac computers with mono and Xamarin studio.

I use this code for building:

```
macpack -m:1 -o:. -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/lib -r:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/emgucv/bin -r:Assimp32.dll -r:Assimp64.dll -r:cvextern.dll -r:Emgu.CV.dll -r:Emgu.Util.dll -r:libegl.dll -r:libglesv2.dll -r:OpenTK.dll -r:OpenTK.GLControl.dll -r:RH.ImageListView.dll -r:blending.fs -r:blending.vs -r:blendingPl.vs -r:idle.fs -r:idle.vs -r:skelet.vs -r:sprite.png -r:./Libraries -r:./Models -r:./Plugin -r:./Resources -r:./Stages -r:./"Haar Cascades" -n:HeadShop -a:RH.MyProgram.exe
```

where I attach mono lib, emgucv lib and all my dll's from debug folder..

All works good on my machine (where I have mono, xamarin studio and all libs installed), but on a client machine - program doesn't run. It doesn't give any errors, just doesn't appear..

Should user install mono or something else for launch program or my command for building is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to install at least the Mono Runtime. Since it [seems not](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/) possible to install it alone, you may have to install the [Mono Mac Package](http://www.mono-project.com/download/).

However, since mono translate C# code into [Common Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) you have to install at least something that can interpret that code and translate/run it on the CPU - An installation is needed in any case.